# How to get the points in the current scaleView in chartarea c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, charts, point

.net 4 vs2010 winform c#

added some points using

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x,y);
```

then zoom the x axis using

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(a,b);
```

Are the any methods to return all the points on the screen  (b> point.Xvalue >a)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using LINQ, you can do the following:

```
DataPointCollection points = chart1.Series[0].Points;
IEnumerable<DataPoint> range =
    from p in points
    where p.XValue > a && p.XValue < b
    select p;
```

`range` contain all data points whose XValue is greater than `a` and less than `b`.